# How to find convergence/divergence of this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1+\cos(n) \over n^2}$$

I used the comparison test and said that $\sum_{n-1}^\infty {1 \over n^2}$ is comparable and also larger than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1+\cos(n) \over n^2}$, and since $\sum_{n-1}^\infty {1 \over n^2}$ converges by the p-series test, the original series will converge as well. Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: Why is it larger?

Comment: use absolute convergence by comparing the absolute value with $\sum {2\over n^{2}}$

Comment: You may have fun by proving that $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1+\cos n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{12}\left(4\pi^2-6\pi+3\right)$$ with Fourier series techniques.

Comment: See [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). For the latter, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\cos(n)\over n^2} ~=~ \frac{\pi^2}6-\frac\pi2+\frac14.$

Answer (score 2):

$$-1\le\cos x \le 1\implies 0\le\cos x +1\le 2$$

The series you should be comparing with is $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{2}{n^2}$, but otherwise your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Is that because the maximum that the numerator can be is 2?

Comment: @Jay Yes, it is because cos x +1 is always less than or equal to 2, i.e. 2 is an upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

I would make some asymptotic analysis, and say that it is a series win nonnegative terms and that:
$$\frac{1+\cos n}{n^2}=O\Bigl(\frac 1{n^2}\Bigr)$$
The latter is convergent, hence the former is.

Comment: As long as you prove that $|\cos(n)| = O(1)$.

Comment: Ibeg your pardon? It simply means $\cos n$ is bounded which is a basic fact.

Comment: That's the proof.